# Why is borderColor function in chartjs running multiple times, and how to reduce it?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In a chart by chartjs, the function are running multiple times (approx 25), how can I reduce that?

Here is a fiddle consoling the number of times it is running: https://jsfiddle.net/abhishek_soni/38mfez7g/26/

Here is the code:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

let i=0, j=0, k=0; 

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: function() {
      ++i;
      console.log('why this bordercolor running this many times : ', i)
       return 'green'
      },
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: function() {
      k++;
      console.log('why this option running this many times : ', k)
       return false
      },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: function() {
        j++;
        console.log('why this scale running this many times : ', j)
        return true
      }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-asxKqQghC1oBShyhiBwA+YgotaSYKxGP1rcSYTDrB0U6DxwlJjU59B67U8+5/++uFjcuVM8Hh5cokLjZlhm3Vg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2"></script>
```

Comment: are you still having problems?

Comment: Hi Jesper, no I was able to make it work correctly, it was defining options differently, I will add the answer to this question soon.

Also, thanks a lot for answering but that answer didn't solve my problem so I didn't accept it.

Comment: I have added the answer now, hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, problem with default charts and chartjs docs, in general, is that it doesn't mention that all the default options are run every time, and it doesn't happen when you separately define the elements options in options, which we can define.

For example in a line chart, we can do options>elements>line>properties, this will only run after charts have been drawn so this significantly increases the efficiency and reduces processing, also you can reduce the function runs by half by disabling animation on the chart (options> animation: false)

So in my case, I was able to bring 25-time running function to 4 time running function by setting the above-mentioned things correctly.

Here is the updated js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/abhishek_soni/38mfez7g/57/

Also, here is the code snippet :

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

let i = 0,
  j = 0,
  k = 0;

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],

    }]
  },
  options: {
    animation: false, // this reduces it by half as for all animations it's renders twice
    elements: { // this reduces it by number of options, as this is applied after the default options are run.
      line: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: function() {
          ++i;
          console.log('why this bordercolor running this many times : ', i)
          return 'green'
        }
      },
    },
    responsive: function() {
      k++;
      console.log('why this option running this many times : ', k)
      return false
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: function() {
          j++;
          console.log('why this scale running this many times : ', j)
          return true
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-asxKqQghC1oBShyhiBwA+YgotaSYKxGP1rcSYTDrB0U6DxwlJjU59B67U8+5/++uFjcuVM8Hh5cokLjZlhm3Vg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I read in the documentation of ChartJs, borderColor should be Color and also it's Scribtable property, it means you can pass a function with context and options as parameters to have flexible ui

So it should be called each time context and options changed.

You can calculate your color value and pass it instead of passing function.

Comment: Yeah, but I need it as a function, I am scripting it in the following way: https://jsfiddle.net/abhishek_soni/38mfez7g/41/ -- I don't know, why it's not recognizing variable gradient in jsfiddle

Comment: You can also cache the computed color, define a variable outside of the chart with an undefined value; when the chart area is presented, you should check if the variable is undefined, computing gradient and save it into the variable and if it does not, return the variable

Comment: Hi Ali, I could not properly understand how to do what you are saying, can you describe it with a little code please, it would mean a lot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The bordercolor function is called everytime your chart needs to draw a border. If you assumed it would be called once, you can just create your own function and give bordercolor the return value of that function, not the function itself.

> I don't know, why it's not recognizing variable gradient in jsfiddle

If you are trying to create a gradient, why would the amount of times this function is called matter in any way? I don't think you understand what you are asking.

Here is your example with a gradient, assuming that is what you actually need: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesper02/mfxebk5j/17/)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

let width, height, gradient;
function getGradient(ctx, chartArea) {
  const chartWidth = chartArea.right - chartArea.left;
  const chartHeight = chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top;
  if (gradient === null || width !== chartWidth || height !== chartHeight) {
    // Create the gradient because this is either the first render
    // or the size of the chart has changed
    width = chartWidth;
    height = chartHeight;
    gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, chartArea.bottom, 0, chartArea.top);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(54, 162, 235)");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "rgb(255, 205, 86)");
    gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(255, 99, 132)");
  }

  return gradient;
}

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: function(context) {
        const chart = context.chart;
        const {ctx, chartArea} = chart;

        if (!chartArea) {
          // This case happens on initial chart load
          return null;
        }
        return getGradient(ctx, chartArea);
      },
      borderWidth: 1
     }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      }
    },
  }
});
```

Taken from [here.](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.2.0/samples/advanced/linear-gradient.html#linear-gradient)